# How to have the HTML tags wrapped in the right order in php?

Tags: php, html, regex, dom, dom-manipulation

I have some HTML codes which is not perfect. For example, I have

```
<b><i>bold and italic</b></i>
```

I want to make it to be wrapped in layers, ie.

```
<b><i>bold and italic</i></b>
```

How can I do that in php?

Answer (score 0):

We can match the two open/close tags and swipe the `textContent`, then replace it using a `preg_replace`:

```
$re = '/(<.+>)(<.+>)(.+)(<\/.+>)(<\/.+>)/s';
$str = '<b><i>bold and italic</b></i>';
$subst = "$1$2$3$5$4";

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);

echo $result;
```

#### Output

```
<b><i>bold and italic</i></b>
```

[image]

#### RegEx

If this wasn't your desired expression, you can modify/change your expressions in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/cIqTl2/1/).

#### RegEx Circuit

You can also visualize your expressions in [jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24):

[image]

Comment: thanks, but there could possibly 3 tags or more, how can I handle it? eg.`<p><b><i>bold and italic</b></i></p>`